# NavigationStack and navigationDestination are not functioning properly

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm a SwiftUI beginner and I'm building a grid layout page with the new Navigation API in SwiftUI 4.0. I want to navigate to an editing page when a grid item is tapped. However, when I try to tap on it, it doesn't navigate correctly, and the console prints the following message:

```
`A NavigationLink is presenting a value of type "Block" but there is no matching navigationDestination declaration visible from the location of the link. The link cannot be activated.

Note: Links search for destinations in any surrounding NavigationStack, then within the same column of a NavigationSplitView.`
```

I'm not sure what went wrong, and it has been bothering me for a while. I hope you can help me. Thank you very much!

Here is my code:

```
struct KnowledgeBaseView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Notebook.order, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var notebooks: FetchedResults<Notebook>
    
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()
    
    func createNewNotebook() -> Notebook {
        let notebook = Notebook(context: viewContext)
        notebook.order = Int16(notebooks.count)
        
        let block = Block(context: viewContext)
        block.typeValue = .page
        block.notebook = notebook
        block.linkedNotebook = notebook
        
        notebook.rootBlock = block
        
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
            return notebook
        } catch {
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
    }
    
    func removeNotebook(notebook: Notebook) -> Void {
        withAnimation {
            viewContext.delete(notebook)
            
            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(.clear)
                        .frame(height: 16)
                    LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(), GridItem(), GridItem()], spacing: 16) {
                        ForEach(notebooks) { notebook in
                            NavigationLink(value: notebook.rootBlock) {
                                NotebookView(notebook: notebook) {
                                    removeNotebook(notebook: notebook)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        AddingNotebookButton {
                            let newNotebook = createNewNotebook()
                            path.append(newNotebook.rootBlock)
                        }
                    }
                    .navigationDestination(for: Block.self) {block in
                        EditingView(block: block)
                    }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 16)
            }
            .navigationTitle("")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Text("Knowledge Base")
                        .textStyle(.xl)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .foregroundColor(Color("PrimaryColor"))
                }
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: {}) {
                        Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle")
                            .fontWeight(.medium)
                            .foregroundColor(Color("PrimaryColor"))
                    }
                }
            }
            .background(Color("BackgroundColor"))
            .rgDefaultNavStyle()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please provide a MRE https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ? Just reduce the entire code to the things relevant to the navigation problem so that it can be copied and built